# Java search for a string and get following lines (until empty line)

Tags: java, search, bufferedreader

The file I am searching in looks sth like this:

```
            keyword: 
            ====================
            category1:
            ----------
            St2
            Dpe
            Tmot:
            Bnw
            category2:
            ----------
            Rer
            Loo


            keyword2:
            ====================
            .
            .
            .
```

What I want to do:

1. search for the line that contains keyword (with ":" append)
2. read all following lines into a list
3. stop when line is empty

In my example I'd call my search function with "keyword" and it would add everything from line "====================" until "Loo" to the list

I already have a dirty solution for this, but it goes crazy in case the searched keyword actually is not in the textfile:

```
BufferedReader b = null;

try {
    b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtfile));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// search for the keyword and save the corresponding text block in a list
while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) 
{
    if(readLine.contains(keyword) && !(readLine.contains("_"+keyword)))
    {
        System.out.println("keyword is: " + readLine);
        while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            if(readLine.trim().isEmpty()) //stop at empyt line
            {
                break;
            } else {
                arr.add(readLine); // add element to list
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*The !(readLine.contains("_"+keyword) statement is there because sometimes the keyword also appears like "Fun_keyword:" and I only want to stop at the "keyword:" line*

**Question**: How can I rewrite this fuction to have it still working correctly (not adding anything to the list) if the keyword is not in the file?

Comment: What do you mean by "it goes crazy in case the searched keyword actually is not in the textfile"? Looking at your code, if the keyword does not exist, your code will do nothing?

Comment: @explv I don't know myself.. it shouldn't do sth, right? But it does print useless lines until heap space overflow when running non existing keywords on my real files

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is your `break` statement breaks the inner while loop when you want it to break the outer loop. Something as follows should work:

```
outerloop: while(true){ //your outer loop
    while(true){ //your inner loop
        if(keywordIsFound){
            break outerloop;
        }
    }
}
```

Naming the outerloop allows the break function to break that loop specifically, not the inner loop.

Comment: Mmm this seems good at first glance. I'll test it further and let you know if it solved the problem

Comment: Did this help at all @jacklaag ?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't that clear what you want to accomplish. But I have assume you want a result like:

> myKeyword -> myValueAssociatedToMyKeyWord

In my opinion, you should break your task to small pieces (functions). Like read your file, parse your block, find a keyword. You also should define what is a keyword (finishing with ':' and following with a line with at least 6x '=' for example). And don't forget to escape all lines that are not interesting in your result (like '-------', ....).

So here is my result:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Read file
        final List<String> lines = readWholeFile("text.txt");
        System.out.println("Read " + lines.size() + " lines.");

        // Extract block with keyword
        final Map<String, List<String>> result = mapBlockToKeyword(lines);

        // Print out the result
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : result.entrySet()) {
            String keyword = entry.getKey();
            entry.getValue().forEach(w -> System.out.println(keyword + " -> " + w));
        }

    }

    private static Map<String, List<String>> mapBlockToKeyword(final List<String> lines) {
        final Map<String, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
        String lastKeyword = "<undefined>";
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            final String line = lines.get(i);

            // Is it a keyword?
            if(isKeyword(line, lines, i)){
                lastKeyword = line;
                if(result.get(lastKeyword) == null){
                    result.put(lastKeyword, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                continue;
            } 

            // Is it a line we don't want to put in our result?
            if (  lineHasAtLeastNTimesConsequtiveSameChar(line, 6, '=') || //
                    lineHasAtLeastNTimesConsequtiveSameChar(line, 6, '-') || //
                    line.trim().isEmpty()) {
                    // We don't want '======' to be associate to a keyword,
                    // escape it.
                    continue;
            }

            // Is it a value to add to keyword ?
            if (result.get(lastKeyword) != null) {
                result.get(lastKeyword).add(line);
            } else {
                System.err.println("Try to associate a value to a non-existant keyword.");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static boolean isKeyword(final String currentLine, final List<String> lines, final int idxLine){
        final boolean hasNextLine = (lines.size() - 1 <= idxLine) ? false : true;
        if (hasNextLine) {
            final String nextLine = lines.get(idxLine + 1);
            // To be a keyword, it has to have a next line and ends with ':'
            if (    hasNextLine && //
                    stringEndsWithChar(currentLine, ':') && //
                    lineHasAtLeastNTimesConsequtiveSameChar(nextLine, 6, '=')) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static List<String> readWholeFile(final String path) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // Would be better in a logger
            System.err.println("Cannot find the file: " + e.getStackTrace());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Would be better in a logger
            System.err.println("Cannot read the file: " + e.getStackTrace());
        }
        return lines;
    }

    private static boolean stringEndsWithChar(String line, char c) {
        if (line != null && line.length() > 1) {
            char lastLineChar = line.charAt(line.length() - 1);
            return lastLineChar == c;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean lineHasAtLeastNTimesConsequtiveSameChar(final String line, int nTimes, char c) {
        if (line != null && line.length() >= nTimes) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*("+c+"{"+nTimes+",}).*$");
            return pattern.matcher(line).find();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

The result:

```
> Read 19 lines. 
> keyword2: -> . 
> keyword2: -> . 
> keyword2: -> . 
> keyword: -> category1: 
> keyword: -> St2 
> keyword: -> Dpe 
> keyword: -> Tmot: 
> keyword: -> Bnw 
> keyword: -> category2: 
> keyword: -> Rer 
> keyword: -> Loo
```

I hope it can help.

With this mapping, you can easly print in the format you want.

Still remaining to do:

- unit tests (important!)
- printing in the right format
- adjust the code to your goal