# Find string and print next lines until empty line

Tags: java

I have a file in the following format

```
USER1
foo
foo

USER2
foo
bar
foo

USER3
bar
bar
```

I want to find a USER - e.g. USER2 and print the next lines up until the empty line

In Unix I could do something like

```sh
cat $FILE | sed -n '/USER2/,/^$/p'
```

Which would give the output

```
foo
bar
foo
```

How can I do similar in Java? I'm OK to read the file, run a for line in loop and find the "USER2" but not sure how I would get the next lines until the empty line?

Comment: Snippets are only intended for HTML/JavaScript/CSS, please use normal code blocks for other languages.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far? Without it you can get some pseudo code at best.

Comment: Apologies - on a corporate network so I cannot login and upload code. (only view these pages)

Answer (score 2):

On StackOverflow it is expected etiquette to post the code you have tried to write, so that answerers can focus on helping you with your specific mistakes, rather than asking for a from-scratch solution. Nevertheless, here you go:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class SO {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
            boolean blank = false;
            boolean found = false;
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.strip().equals("")) {
                    blank = true;
                    found = false;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    blank = false;
                }
                if (line.equals("USER1")) {
                    found = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if (!blank && found) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike - I'm on a corporate network so cannot log onto this site and upload code - so apologies for the limited info - I had been trying the code mentioned on this page but it was not working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635135/java-search-for-a-string-and-get-following-lines-until-empty-line - I will try what you suggested - Thank you.

Comment: Perfect! - Thank you Mike